# How to navigate to specified panorama item from another page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, panorama-control

I have `MainPage.xaml` and `PanoramaPage1.xaml`.

How can I navigate from `MainPage` to `Item1` or `Item2` in `PanoramaPage`?

For example: 
`Button1->Item1` and `Button2->Item2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a standard navitaion:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("PanoramaPage1.xaml?buttonid=button1",UriKind.Relative));
```

Pass your target in object varible and then handle in panomarama page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  if ( this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey( "buttonid" ) 
  {
      string buttonid = this.NavigationContext.QueryString[ "buttonid" ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Error: No overload for method 'Navigate' takes 2 arguments

Comment: Ok so I have my parameter now, I can use `if(parameter.Equals("1") NAVIGATE_TO_ITEM1; else NAVIGATE_TO_ITEM2;` but how can I navigate to panorama items?

Comment: look here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aschapiro/archive/2012/07/21/navigating-directly-to-a-specific-screen-inside-a-panorama-or-pivot-page.aspx

Comment: I mean I can't use Panorama.DefaultItem, PanoramaPage1.DefaultItem or this.DefaultItem in OnNavigatedTo method

Comment: So try other event On_Load or something. You always check for parameter exis so will be no problem.

Comment: Ohhh I added x:name to my panorama control and it works now. Thx for help